# PHP Radio Buttons forms example

Tags: php

So lets say i have the following example how can i get values from radio buttons and acctualy work with those values? You can see that i tried something but i can't find it how to make it work ..

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand">My learning skills: A self-assessment questionnaire</a></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <form role="form" method="post">
                     <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Nume:</label><input class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter name" type="text"></div>
                     <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address:</label><input class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email"></div>
                     <div class="container">
                        <div class= "row">
                            <h4>Your gender: *</h4> 
                        </div>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">F</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">M</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Your age: *</label><input class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter age" type="text"></div>
         </div>



          <div class= "row">
                            <h2>That was it! Please, keep your scores saved and check that after refilling in this questionnaire, in 6-8 months from now on. Happy learning!</h2>

                        </div>
           <div class= "row">
           <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
           </div>
        </div>

                  </form>
                <?php $gender = $_POST['contact']; echo $gender; ?>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As example:

echo $gender;
and the results should be $female

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $gender = $_POST['contact']; echo $gender; ?>
```

Change this to

```
<?php $gender = $_POST['gender']; echo $gender; ?>.
```

Name of your radio control is gender not contact.